# how to change Fontfamily in BottomNavigationBarItem Flutter label?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-android

```
items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home', // this i want to change font family
        ),
```

],

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuPV7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

`BottomNavigationBar` has properties like

`TextStyle? selectedLabelStyle` and
`TextStyle? unselectedLabelStyle`

Using these properties, you can assign TextStyle to your label text and change the fontStyle/font family of the `BottomNavigationBar` item.